# Cryptocurrency chart to reflect the last 7 day performance

Tags: python, django, coinbase-api, coinmarketcap

I am trying to generate the last 7 days performance for a number of tokens in `Django`. Please refer to the coinmarketcap.com which shows the performance of a token for last 7 days.

I am getting the real-time price data from Coinbase API. I donot want to store huge historical data in order to generate the chart below.

I am looking into the number of APIs which provides the summary of historical data to generate the  line chart below.

Any idea/pointers would be really helpful. As a solution, I am planning to display the same chart as in coinmarketcap:

https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/2781/1.svg

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution could be using the free widget of tradingview, it's just HTML code, to integrate it use something that can render html.

This solution is not really what you are looking for because it's interactive, you can take a look about their widgets [here](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/) maybe there is something that could interest you.

---

One other approach if you can't find what you want is using ccxt library. This library allows you to connect, perform trades, see market data of a lot of crypto exchanges.

The majority of crypto exchange don't require authentication to see market data like FTX. You can see a code example on python on how to get data.

[Ccxt documentation](https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html)

```py
import ccxt
import datetime

exchange = ccxt.ftx()
since = datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()*1000 - (7*24*3600*1000)

data = exchange.fetchOHLCV (symbol, timeframe = '1d', since = since)
```

Then you can use matplotlib or plotly to render the data the way you want if you use python

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this does not provide the granular data necessary to generate the graph right?

Comment: To generate the graph you just need close values, here you have open, close, high, low, volume and timestamp. Select what you want, define the color of your plot by calculating if during the 7 days time window returns are positive or negative